# Cannot read property 'includes' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue.js with JavaScript.

I have an array of objects called `products` and every object has the `property` called `smallest_unit_barcode`. I want to filter only products with barcode like `value`, so I did this function:

```js
if (value != '') {
    var results = this.products.filter(obj=>obj.smallest_unit_barcode.includes(value));
    var results = results.slice(Math.max(results.length - 20, 0))
    this.pos_quick_lunch = results;
}
```

Everything works fine, but if `obj.smallest_unit_barcode == null`, I get this error:

```
Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null"
```

How can I ignore the `null` value when filtering the products array?

Comment: `if ( obj.smallest_unit_barcode === null) ... else ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compare against `null` before you try to access the property:

```
obj => obj.smallest_unit_barcode !== null && obj.smallest_unit_barcode.includes(value)
```

Because `&&` is [*short circuiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), the right operand won't be evaluated if the left operand evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is, You can use **?** with includes

```
if (value != '') {
    var results = this.products.filter(obj=>obj?.smallest_unit_barcode?.includes(value));
    var results = results.slice(Math.max(results.length - 20, 0))
    this.pos_quick_lunch = results;
}
```